# How to improve page loading time while processing more than two hundred thousand records?

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework, postgresql-8.4, php-5.4

I've an array with `251002` elements which are the child offices for a particular parent office. This is in the key value format, with an `office id` as key and `office name` as value. 
This is the format of the array.

> Array   (
>       [1] => Test Office 1
>       [2] => Test Office 2
>       [3] => Test Office 3
>       [4] => Test Office 4
>       .
>       .
>       upto 251002 array elements
>   )

This array serves as the option for a select box which inturn is used for selecting an office while adding a user. So while a user is being created, whoever creates that user, needs to select one office name from the options provided in the selectbox.

The issue that I'm facing here is the loading time. It takes an awful lot of time for the page to get loaded and the browser is getting hanged frequently. So, What's the solution? How can I quickly load the page with all the options set in the select box? Autosuggest seems  to be a good option. But to find a match-case for each key press, I need to parse though the same child office table that contain these 200k rows.

**Additional details:**
**Query Executed**

> SELECT child.childoffice_id, child.childoffice_name FROM
>   child WHERE (child.parentoffice_id IN('11416', '11876', '11877', '5742', '5743', '10053', '3244', '14620', '13950', '12772', '18842', '15346', '5756', '16149', '17989', '3687', '15819', '15384', '10841', '18069', '10842', '16416', '17279', '18483', '14386', '16222', '11858', '16019', '10963', '13622', '15569', '15570', '14840', '16432', '17102', '15110', '12249', '16092', '16260'))
>   AND (child.deleted=0) AND (child.childoffice_status= '1')  ORDER BY
>   child.childoffice_name ASC

"There can be any number of parent offices"

**The query execution details:**

> **Total query runtime**: 14457 ms.
>   251002 rows retrieved.

I'm working with `zend framework 1.11` with `postgresql 8.4` as the backend

Comment: Why would you load 200k values into an array? Use autocomplete.

Comment: @JakubKania Well, that's a good suggestion and I've though about it. But to match an autocompleted list I've to compare the typed data against these 200k values via ajax, and that too on each key press.

Comment: On each keypress? Don't think so, usually autocomplete starts when you type 3 first letters, only a fraction of those 200k should start with the same names. And with a proper index it will be blitz.

Comment: Lazy autocomplete - delay until a few letters are typed, and delay sending a query for a few hundred ms so that you don't send queries that become obsolete immediately due to a new keypress. Do the search server-side (i.e. use the SQL WHERE clause). Also: **plan on upgrading PostgreSQL** as you're on an obsolete version.

Comment: @JakubKania Oh! I forgot to mention about index. I've indexed the child table(using BTREE). Regarding keypress, I've said that purposefully, because some of the office name contains only 1 or 2 letters.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you. I'll definitely take a look at the Lazy autocomplete. 
Yes I'm planning to move to an upgraded version of Postgresql

Comment: Well, even if the office name is only one letter that still means you'd have to send 10k records not 200k, and for people that want offices that have normal names things will be much faster.

Comment: Avoid big `IN` lists like that. Use `WHERE EXISTS (...)` or a `VALUES` list.

Comment: @JakubKania Agreed. I'll try it out and will surely update this question with more details, if there are problems after using autocomplete.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you. It did solve the problem. But out of curiosity, if I need to process such huge volumes of data in an application, what can be done?

Comment: @harry What solved the problem? Lazy autocomplete or changing how you express the query? Both?